# Use pipl with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use [pipl with Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pipl). I have written the following code:

```
router.post('/httpOnly/enrich/pipl', (req, res) => {
    var pipl = require('pipl')('BUSINESS-PREMIUM-DEMO-xyozhmgkc57085z7...');
    pipl.search.query('json', {"email": "softtimur@gmail.com"}, function(err, data) {
        console.log(data);
        res.json(data)
    });
})
```

However, it gave an error:

```
index.js POST /httpOnly/enrich/pipl
http://api.pipl.com/search/v4/
/.../node_modules/pipl/lib/inherits.js:32
                    return callback(err, JSON.parse(body) || body);
                           ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
    at Request._callback (/.../node_modules/pipl/lib/inherits.js:32:28)
    at Request.self.callback (/.../node_modules/request/request.js:123:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/.../node_modules/request/request.js:893:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:120:20)
    at Request.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/.../node_modules/request/request.js:844:12)
    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1059:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/ArkeologeN/pipl) it looks like the syntax is:

```
pipl.search.query({"email": "softtimur@gmail.com"}, function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
    res.json(data)
});
```

Without the `'json'` string at the beginning. I think the signature was changed without the documentation on npm being updated.

Check [this](https://github.com/ArkeologeN/pipl/commit/c144509d477761ece39cbaf8f6314ffed230382c) commit too.

Comment: Thank you... I got another error `{ '@http_status_code': 403,
  error: 'This API key is for API version 5. You tried using version 4' }`.

Comment: @SoftTimur I see you made an issue on the GitHub repo. You can try removing *v4/* on [this](https://github.com/ArkeologeN/pipl/blob/master/lib/main.js#L17) line and see if that works. According to the [API documentation](https://docs.pipl.com/reference/#overview-1) it looks like they removed the version from the URL. The pipl library you are using is generally out of date, that's the problem.

Comment: Removing that line in my local `node_modules/pipl/lib/main.js` did solve the problem. Now, how could I keep this version even after `sudo npm install`? Do I have to make a bash to systematically replace that file?

Comment: @SoftTimur You can fork the repo on GitHub, fix it in your forked repo and commit, and then link to the GitHub repo in package.json.

Comment: So I will commit a npm package, right? Do I need the permission of the authors to do so?

Comment: You don't have to publish to npm. You can use github links in package.json. E.g. `"pipl": "https://github.com/softtimur/pipl/tarball/master"`. See [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#github-urls). The license is MIT so you can fork it without problems. You only have to retain the copyright notices in the comments. If you haven't forked on GitHub before you can look [here](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/).